# Ordering reference in bibTex

Tags: bibtex

I'm a newbie in LaTeX and BibTeX and using ACM-Reference-Format in bibliographystyle like below code.

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sigproc}
```

The problem is that my reference is not in order...
I wrote the reference in order in `sigproc.bib` but in actual Latex preview which is pdf format, it gives me mixed order.

Here is my `sigproc.bib` that I wrote,

```
@MANUAL{Watson,
  title =    {Watson Internet of Things},
  author =   {IBM},
  note =     {\url{https://www.ibm.com/internet-of-things/iot-zones/iot-buildings/forum/}}
}

@MANUAL{Iso,
  title =    {Ergonomics of the thermal environment - Analytical determination and interpretation of thermal comfort using calculation of the PMV and PPD indices and local thermal comfort criteria},
  author =   {ISO(International Organization for Standardization},
  month =    {May},
  year =    2005,
  note =     {\url{https://www.iso.org/standard/39155.html}}
}

@ARTICLE{Tachi,
    author = {Tomokazu Tachikawa, Akihiro Oda, Toshihiko Handa, Jun'ichi Ichimura, Yuji Watanabe, Hiroaki Nishi},
    title = {Cooperative Distributed Demand Control by Environmental Sensor Network - Estimating the Number of People by CO2 Concentration},
    journal = {The IEEE International Conference on Industrial Informatics 2008 (INDIN2008)},
    pages = {36-341},
    month = {July},
    year = {2008},
    doi = {10.1109/INDIN.2008.4618119},
}

@ARTICLE{Knives,
    author = {T. Handa, C. Roesener, J. Ichimura, H. Nishi},
    title = {KNIVES: Network  based Demand and Supply Control System},
    journal = {The IEEE International  Conference on Industrial Informatics 2007 (INDIN 2007)},
    pages = {1171-1176},
    month = {June},
    year = {2007},
    doi = {10.1109/INDIN.2007.4384896},
}

@BOOK{Japan,
  author =   {Environmetal science forum},
  title =    {Story of room air pollution},
  publisher =    {Japanese Standards Association},
  address =  {Japan},
  month = {October},
  year =     2002,
  isbn =     {4542902587}
}
```

However, it shows me like `Iso` first, and then `watson` as second. I want it to be like ordering as above itself.
How can I order the references?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please edit your question and add a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: The syntax in the `author` fields is all wrong. To separate authors, use the keyword `and`, *not* commas. BibTeX should be issuing lots of warning messages about "too many commas" in the `Tachi` entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ACM-Reference-Format` bibliography style is designed to sort the entries in alphabetical order by authors' surnames. (The sorting order in the bib file is irrelevant.) If alphabetical sorting by surnames is not what you want, you should probably not be using the `ACM-Reference-Format` bibliography style.

Do note that one must use the keyword `and` to separate authors in the `author` fields. Using commas isn't correct. BibTeX should have been issuing lots of warning messages to this effect -- did you notice them?

A separate issue: Three of the five entries have so-called "corporate authors": "IBM", "ISO (International Organization for Standardization)", and "Environmental Science Forum". In order to assure that they're sorted correctly, it's necessary to encase these fields in double curly braces, as is done in the following example.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sigproc.bib}
@MANUAL{Watson,
  title =    {Watson {Internet of Things}},
  author =   {IBM},
  note =     {\url{https://www.ibm.com/internet-of-things/iot-zones/iot-buildings/forum/}}
}

@MANUAL{Iso,
  title =    {Ergonomics of the thermal environment---Analytical determination and interpretation of thermal comfort using calculation of the {PMV} and {PPD} indices and local thermal comfort criteria},
  author =   {{ISO (International Organization for Standardization}},
  month =    {May},
  year =    2005,
  note =     {\url{https://www.iso.org/standard/39155.html}}
}

@ARTICLE{Tachi,
    author = {Tomokazu Tachikawa and Akihiro Oda and Toshihiko Handa and Jun'ichi Ichimura and Yuji Watanabe and Hiroaki Nishi},
    title = {Cooperative Distributed Demand Control by Environmental Sensor Network---{Estimating} the Number of People by {CO2} Concentration},
    journal = {The IEEE International Conference on Industrial Informatics 2008 (INDIN2008)},
    pages = {36-341},
    month = {July},
    year =  {2008},
    doi =   {10.1109/INDIN.2008.4618119},
}

@ARTICLE{Knives,
    author = {T. Handa and C. Roesener and J. Ichimura and H. Nishi},
    title = {{KNIVES}: Network  based Demand and Supply Control System},
    journal = {The IEEE International  Conference on Industrial Informatics 2007 (INDIN 2007)},
    pages = {1171-1176},
    month = {June},
    year =  {2007},
    doi =   {10.1109/INDIN.2007.4384896},
}

@BOOK{Japan,
  author =   {{Environmetal Science Forum}},
  title =    {Story of room air pollution},
  publisher = {Japanese Standards Association},
  address =  {Japan},
  month =    {October},
  year =     2002,
  isbn =     {4542902587}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sigproc}
\end{document}
```